Passing style to GeoServer layer group
We have two layers from PostGIS views defined in Geoserver Layers,
the district layer will be overlayed on the point layer,
and we defined the point layer with total three styles,
we are able to pass the style name using the below function, we can see the available styles in the drop down, but
function setStyle(style){
  map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
  lyr.getSource().updateParams({'STYLES': style});
  });
}

We want to pass the style to the point layer which is defined as group layer, as we can see we are not able to access the style available for the point layer, are we missing something?





If the layer is inside an OpenLayers layer group you can access it using map.getAllLayers()` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#getAllLayers

It makes no sense to group those 2 layers, one is static and could be tiled. The other is dynamic and probably can't be cached, especially if you want the user to change the style.

Thank you for your comments Mike, and @Ian Turton, your suggestion make sense, but is it possible to pass style argument to on of the layer to layer group? if so please point us
